# How to set values in Input<input> and Select <select> tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an auto-set of values in input or select tag based on the condition provided in the java script below:
My problem here is that whenever i submit the data i wont reflect in the database. Any idea or a snippets of code would a great help.

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var condition = document.getElementById("course").value;
    var text

    if(condition==="BSCS"|| condition==="BSIT"|| condition==="BSIS"||condition==="BLIS"||condition==="BSEMC")
    {
        text="Department A";
    }
    else if(condition==="BSA"||condition==="BSBA"||condition==="BSOA"||condition==="BSREM"||condition==="BSHRM"){
        text="Department B";
    }else if(condition==="BEED"||condition==="BSED"||condition==="BSSW"||condition==="AB-PolScie"||condition==="AB-Philo"||condition==="AB-English"){
        text="Department C";
    }else{
        text="N/A";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}
```

```html
<select id="course" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-control" 
name="Course">
                <option value="None">Select Course</option>
                <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
                <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You heve used `innerHTML` which is wrong if you want to set a value, use `value`.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
```

change to:

```
document.getElementById("demo").value=text;
```

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var condition = document.getElementById("course").value;
    var text

    if(condition==="BSCS"|| condition==="BSIT"|| condition==="BSIS"||condition==="BLIS"||condition==="BSEMC")
    {
        text="Department A";
    }
    else if(condition==="BSA"||condition==="BSBA"||condition==="BSOA"||condition==="BSREM"||condition==="BSHRM"){
        text="Department B";
    }else if(condition==="BEED"||condition==="BSED"||condition==="BSSW"||condition==="AB-PolScie"||condition==="AB-Philo"||condition==="AB-English"){
        text="Department C";
    }else{
        text="N/A";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").value=text;
}
```

```html
<select id="course" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-control" 
name="Course">
  <option value="None">Select Course</option>
  <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
  <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
</select>

<input id="demo" type="text" name="Dept" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" required>
```